# How to lazy static define a const mutable vector which I can push to from macro logic called from outer scope?

Tags: rust

I need to populate this vector and use it somewhere in my code, I don't know where I should put it. I also want to push into the vector at will at various places in my logic:

```
  let rc = RookCheck::new();
  let kp = K123P::new();
  let ptts: Vec<&dyn Patt> = vec![&rc, &kp];
```

So I have macro that defines a struct, and I want to push the instance of that struct into this ptts:

```
// Define a macro that can modify ptts
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($ptts:expr) => {
     // Implement SomeAnotherPatt and the Patt trait for it

        let some_another_patt = SomeAnotherPatt; 
        $ptts.push(Box::new(some_another_patt));
    };
}
```

But I want to call this my_macro from the outer scope out of main closure.

```
fn main() {}

// where should I put ptts?

my_macro!(ptts);
```